# perf: understanding why a specific instruction is "hot"

Tags: linux, performance, assembly, profiling, perf

When I profile using perf, I usually see 1 or 2 "hot" instructions.

The default metric for perf is **cycles**, so perf is actually telling me that those instructions cost alot in terms of cycles.

I am trying to find out how to figure out **why** a specific instruction takes alot of cycles.

There are probably alot of reasons:

1. cache miss
2. branch prediction failure
3. other kind of stalls

For example,

while profiling my code I saw that this instruction is marked in red:

```
lea    -0xf(%rsi),%eax
```

I switched to another metric **L1-dcache-loads** or **cache-misses**

but this instruction is not marked in red under any of those metrics.

So besides blindly searching all the metrics, how can I find out why a specific instruction is costly in terms of cycles using perf ?

Thanks,

Itay

Comment: There's really only one reason why a simple arithmetic instruction like that can use a lot cycles and that's because it's executed a lot. In other words it would be have to part of a loop. Note that because perf uses a sample based method measuring cycles, the numbers shown can be very misleading.

Comment: @RossRidge - so LEA is actually only calculating memory without touching it... i see...however, this was just an example, any idea on how to zoom in a memory access operation - simply trying out all the relevant metrics ?

Comment: Itay, sometimes wrong instruction can be red (offset of several instructions; or marking as slow usage of some value, but not the load of the value from memory); please add to your question near instructions too. How rsi was generated?